# Help compiling in UNIX

Tags: unix, compiler-construction, compilation

I am using 000host as my server which is Unix.
I need a program compiled but I am running windows on my computer...
here is the program:
http://www.weather.gov/mdl/degrib/howto.php

here is how to compile it:
http://www.weather.gov/mdl/degrib/compile.php?os=unix

As far as i am aware, i cannot do this via windows. Would someone be willing to do it for me so i can use the program on my server?
If i am able to somehow do it, could you let me know how?

thanks or the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you compiling on your 000host unix server. Is there some problem with that? A binary compiled on another "UNIX" is unlikely to work unless they were pretty compiled on a machine with identical UNIX version and libraries. If at all you want to compile elsewhere just looking for "UNIX" won't do, you'll have to be more detailed than that.

Comment: how would i compile on the 000host server. im not sure i know what you mean

Comment: Do you have ssh / telnet access? If not can you get it?

Answer (score 0):

There are various utilities available to interact with UNIX server from windows machine.
Some of the utilities are:
1. TELNET
2. PUTTY

Using above utilities you can log in to UNIX machine and then with the help UNIX shell prompt you can follow compile steps.